# Get an ordered list in lxml objectify

Tags: python, lxml

If I have an ordered list in XML

```
<Boa>
    <Channels>
        <Channel name="Red"/>
        <Channel name="Green"/>
        <Channel name="Blue" />
    </Channels>
</Boa>
```

This code

```
from lxml import objectify

Boa = objectify.parse(self.xml).getroot()
```

only gets me

```
Boa.Channels.Channel
```

with a single entry for Channel.

How do I get this as an ordered list in lxml objectify?  I'm also fine with changing my XML markup if there's something that lxml expects to automatically do the conversion.

Comment: this might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390653/getting-contents-of-an-lxml-objectify-comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

objectify is a bit weird as it tries to map xml to python objects and this is not 100% match so it has to compromise.

`Boa.Channels.Channel` is the first `Channel`

```
>>> Boa.Channels.Channel.get('name')
'Red'
```

But at the same time it can also work as a list of `Channel`s:

```
>>> Boa.Channels.Channel[0].get('name')
'Red'
>>> Boa.Channels.Channel[1].get('name')
'Green'
>>> Boa.Channels.Channel[2].get('name')
'Blue'
>>> [c.get('name') for c in Boa.Channels.Channel]
['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
```